# What's the difference between gnome, gnome-shell, and gnome-session-fallback?

Tags: package-management

I have the Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop freshly installed. If i execute the following command, what exactly happens?

```
sudo apt-get install gnome
```

And what is the difference between the above command and installing `gnome-shell` or `gnome-session-fallback`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to expand on [Uri Herrera](https://askubuntu.com/users/4203/uri-herrera) above [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/171393/63025) .

What is Gnome ?

It is basically a [meta package](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gnome-shell/) consisting Both **gnome-shell** and **gnome-fallback session**.

[GNOME Shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Shell) uses **Mutter**, a compositing window manager based on the **Metacity window manager**, and **the Clutter toolkit to provide visual effects and hardware acceleration**. According to GNOME Shell maintainer Owen Taylor, it is set up as a **Mutter plugin largely written in Javascript.**

From [Gnome official page](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/FAQ#What_is_GNOME_shell.3F)

> Gnome-shell provides core interface functions like switching to
>   windows and launching applications. GNOME Shell takes advantage of the
>   capabilities of **modern graphics hardware and introduces innovative
>   user interface concepts** to provide a delightful and easy to use
>   experience.

You can refer the [technology behind GNOME Shell page](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Technology).

[What is Fallback-mode?](http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/3.3/fallback-mode.html.en)

> **If your computer's graphics card doesn't support certain features, a more basic version of the desktop will be displayed** and you will see
>   a message telling you what happened. This is called **fallback mode**,
>   and it allows you to use GNOME on your computer without some of its
>   more advanced features..
>
> ..**Starting in fallback mode doesn't necessarily mean that your
>   graphics card isn't good enough to run GNOME** - it might just mean
>   that you don't have the right drivers installed for your graphics
>   card. If you can find better graphics card drivers for your computer,
>   you may be able to run the full version of GNOME.

Basically it is for **Unsupported Graphic Cards**

Comment: It should probably be added that "gnome-fallback session" is a session manager. Or rather the session manager is probably called GNOME Fallback session. I mean, "... session" doesn't sound like a program name. As such, it should be mentioned explicitly. That is, if I got it right.

Answer (score 7):

If you check on the description of `gnome`

> The GNOME Desktop Environment, *with extra components*

It will install both the Gnome Shell, and the Fallback session, along with the Gnome games, Evolution, Epiphany, Empathy, Rhythmbox, etc. It will install *everything* gnome.

Whereas `gnome-shell` will install just the Gnome Shell and its dependencies. Same is for the the fallback session package.

You can get this info either from Synaptic or using `apt-cache show gnome` and `apt-cache show gnome-shell`.

Comment: Thanks for the apt-cache command, I didn't know that before.