# How to connect Ubuntu Server GUI from Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: 14.04, server, gui, remote-desktop

I have running instance on AWS EC2 where I have installed Ubuntu server 14.04. Here I want to access it using GUI for that I am following this tutorial: [youtube link for GUI Ubuntu Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TytIcOXC2zM)

I am entering these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lxde
sudo start lxdm
sudo apt-get install xrdp
sudo passwd ubuntu
```

But here I am unable to access the GUI as in this tutorial, they are using windows but I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I can see a remmina remote desktop client but it is not connecting. I need help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about LXDE as I have no experience with it. However, if the goal is simply to get a GUI then you can probably achieve it easier by using Gnome. You can also use VNC over SSH for remote desktop capabilities.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Refer to the following article if you need help with that.

[install gnome-shell on ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766071/install-gnome-shell-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: My question is to connect the desktop using my ubunut remote desktop or something can I do this

Comment: I don't see why not. There are several "remote desktop" applications available for Linux. The easiest is probably running VNC over SSH.

Comment: I did that but it is showing grey screen

Comment: Is the grey screen happening when remoting in or is this when accessing the GUI from a local screen? Also did you receive any errors while installing Gnome?

Comment: Great to hear! If my answer helped please vote it up! If you solved it completely on your own then please create an answer... it may help others in the future! :-)

Comment: You should also mention about vncserver and xvncviewer in the edit