# How can I remove Budgie desktop?

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu Budgie 22.10 but I did not like it so I would like to go back to Ubuntu without any flavors. Is it possible to do that without re-installing?

Comment: Note that you can choose to open Ubuntu (GNOME) instead of Ubuntu Budgie in your login screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [install gnome-shell on ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766071/install-gnome-shell-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: I'd likely just reverse the method you used to install it.  As the Budgie desktop uses the GNOME desktop in its operation (*it's mostly just a front-end that replaces the GNOME Shell the user sees but using GNOME underneath*) you want to ensure no packages of GNOME don't get removed (*but if they do, OR you just want to be sure, run a `apt install ubuntu-desktop` to correct packages*).  Some pieces (like `plymouth` screens) still need you to manually change as just wallpaper/optional components.